# @ and & in PHP, when used with variables

Tags: php, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I've seen in PHP some variables that are set like this:

```
$var = @$something;
```

Or functions set like this:

```
$var = &my_function();
```

What effect do the @ and the & have?

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Didn't know where to look (other than the operators page)

Answer (score 5):

You have them backwards. `&$variable` means "a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to this variable." `@my_function()` means "call this function and [suppress any errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) or warnings that it produces."

Comment: can we please not answer this because its a duplicate of duplicates

Answer (score 2):

@ means "don't report errors"

& means "take a reference to the following variable instead of copying its value"

Comment: closevote. you haz the reputation for it. use it

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the two (take a reference, copy)?

Answer (score 2):

`@` operator in php is used to ignore errors in that statement.
Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

`&` is reference operator.
Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Answer (score 1):

`@` causes to hide all errors. In case of variables, it might be E_NOTICE informing about variable not existing.

The `&my_function();` is invalid - `&` is normally used for references, it doesn't nothing in this case.